# Sugarcube game editing using for loops

Tags: javascript, loops, twine, sugarcube

I'm very new to Sugarcube, I learned that you can edit values by inspecting on the browser. My question is how do you use a loop to change the value of a bunch of things at once?
For instance if a game looks like this

> ShoppingCart

> > Milk
> > cost=10

> > Meat
> > cost=20

> > Bread
> > cost=30

How do I make a loop to say

for i in ShoppingCart:

i.cost = 10;

end

or something to that effect? I have some coding knowledge of other languages but not this.
Until now I've been doing

SugarCube.State.variables.ShoppingCart.Milk=10

SugarCube.State.variables.ShoppingCart.Meat=10

SugarCube.State.variables.ShoppingCart.Bread=10

but its getting tedious, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For in loops through key

```
const cart = SugarCube.State.variables.ShoppingCart
for(let i in cart) {
   if(cart[i].cost != undefined ) continue; 
   cart[i].cost = 10 
}
```

Comment: Wow this works, is there also a code to check if cost exists in cart[i] then cart[i].cost=10 else do nothing?

Comment: If the above helped, please accept the answer.

Comment: you can add if(cart[i].cost != undefined ) continue; in the first line of the loop

Comment: Thank you and do we include the continue; or is that where we write the code? And how do we end the if statement?